# JoinableQueue between two process, Two processes are blocking forever sometimes

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am writing multiprocess program. There are four class: **Main**, **Worker**, **Request** and **Ack**. The Main class is the entry point of program. It will create the sub-process called Worker to do some jobs. The main process put the Request into JoinableQueue, and than Worker get request from queue. When Worker finished the request, it will put the ACK into queue. The part of code shown as below:

---

**Main:**

```
class Main():
    def __init__(self):
        self.cmd_queue = JoinableQueue()
        self.worker = Worker(self.cmd_queue)

    def call_worker(self, cmd_code):
        if self.cmd_queue.empty() is True:
            request = Request(cmd_code)
            self.cmd_queue.put(request)
            self.cmd_queue.join()
            ack = self.cmd_queue.get()
            self.cmd_queue.task_done()
            if ack.value == 0:
                return True
            else:
                return False
        else:
            # TODO: Error Handling.
            pass

    def run_worker(self):
        self.worker.start()
```

**Worker:**

```
class Worker(Process):
    def __init__(self, cmd_queue):
        super(Worker, self).__init__()
        self.cmd_queue = cmd_queue
    ...
    def run(self):
        while True:
            ack = Ack(0)
            try:
                request = self.cmd_queue.get()
                if request.cmd_code == ReqCmd.enable_handler:
                    self.enable_handler()
                elif request.cmd_code == ReqCmd.disable_handler:
                    self.disable_handler()
                else:
                    pass
            except Exception:
                ack.value = -1
            finally:
                self.cmd_queue.task_done()
                self.cmd_queue.put(ack)
                self.cmd_queue.join()
```

---

It often works normally. But Main process stuck at self.cmd_queue.join(), and the Worker stuck at self.cmd_queue.join() sometimes. It is so weird! Does anyone have any ideas? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing *weird* in the above issue: you shouldn't call queue's `join` within a typical single worker process activity because 
`Queue.join()`

> Blocks until **all** items in the queue have been gotten and
>   processed.

Such a calls where they are in your current implementation will make the processing pipeline wait.

Usually `queue.join()` is called in the main (supervisor) thread after initiating/starting all threads/workers.

https://docs.python.org/3/library/queue.html#queue.Queue.join

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I want the work process to respond Ack object to Main via queue. So I call the join() in the worker process to guarantee the main process already get Ack. I think the main process also calls get() and task_done(). It will let queue be empty. I don't understand why it will block forever?